# Coldfusion Time Zone US->UK GMT

Tags: datetime, coldfusion

I am updating some code as we are now on a US server but we are based in the UK so our timezones need to be changed with both dates and times.

I created this script.

```
    <cfset tztemp = GetTimeZoneInfo()>
    <cfset isDST = tztemp.isDSTOn >
    <cfif isDST eq "Yes">
    <cfset dtGMT = #CreateODBCDateTime(DateAdd("s",tztemp.utcTotalOffset+3600,now()))#>
    <cfelse>
    <cfset dtGMT = #CreateODBCDateTime(DateAdd("s",tztemp.utcTotalOffset,now()))#>
    </cfif>
```

My question is how would I change the value #dtGMT#  into the formats below?

```
#DateFormat(Now(), "YYMMDD")#

#TimeFormat(Now(), "HHMM")#
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#DateFormat(dtGMT, "YYMMDD")#`

`#TimeFormat(dtGMT "HHMM")#`

Comment: Excellent, thankyou. I missed removing the brackets from (Now() when I tested so it wasn't working!